# App_Code folder issues

Tags: app-code

The problem that your classes are not compiled, You'll solve this issue simply by going to the properties of any class in the App_Code folder and change it's 'Build Action' property from "Content" to "Compile"

But how can I set the property?

Comment: Property can be set while the project is not running. have u tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the item in the solution explorer, and select Properties.  In the properties window, there is a `Build Action` option.